# Mikrotik RouterOS - NAT to multiple ports on the same IP

Tags: router, firewall, dnat

Some network services require a group of open ports, and those might not even be next to each other (by port number, I mean).

What I'm doing still is I create a dst-nat rule for each port that should be mapped to the server, then enable/disable the rule as needed.

In my specific case, that's a bit tedious because sometimes the ports should point to a different computer for a short period of time which means I have to manually change all the entries to the new IP each time I do this. Also, I wish I could just say "disable service x" instead of figuring out which port rules belong together.

Is there a better and more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a single NAT rule, you can specify multiple ports in the same rule by using a comma separator, or hypen for range, or combination of them both.

So for FTP, I use ports:  21, 990, 65000-65100

If you are also translating ports, you specify the translated ports in the same order.

If I want to temporarily point my rule at another server, I create another rule and place it above my original so that it takes precedence.

Then simply disable the rule and all ports are disable with it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use multiple port on the NAT rules, separated by ","

Comment: This answer was already given. It's great that you want to participate and I welcome you but please post a new answer only if it adds useful information.